# How can I replace each and every word with 3 values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Confusing title, let me explain. I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

`df1` looks like this:

```
id `  text                                 
1     Hello world how are you people     
2     Hello people I am fine  people    
3     Good Morning people               
4     Good Evening
```

`df2` looks like this

```
Word      count         Points         Percentage

hello        2             2              100
world        1             1              100
how          1             1              100
are          1             1              100
you          1             1              100
people       3             1              33.33
I            1             1              100
am           1             1              100
fine         1             1              100
Good         2             -2            -100
Morning      1             -1            -100
Evening      1             -1            -100
```

`df2` contains each & every word one time of `df1`, and they are given three values `count` `points` `percentage`.

First I want to replace each and every word of `df1` with `count` `points` `percentage`. For example: the row one

`Hello world how are you people` will become this `2 2 100 1 1 100 1 1 100 1 1 100 1 1 100 1 1 100`

Because `Hello` = `2 2 100` world = `1 1 100` like that.

Expected output::

```
id `  text                                 
1      2 100 1 1 100 1 1 100 1 1 100 1 1 100 1 1 100
2     2 2 100 3 1 33.33 1 1 100 1 1 100 1 1 100 3 1 33.33 
3     2 -2 -100 1 -1 -100 3 1 33.33            
4     2 -2 -100 1 -1 -100
```

Comment: You still want the `text` column to be one long string?

Comment: For now yes, Then I will make a new column for each and every int number. So total number of columns will be equal to the maximum length of words in the dataframe. Some row has only 2 words, some has 10, so the value will be 0 for the extra columns, if left any. I am not sure if you understood.

Comment: But for now, I just want one long string, I think I will be able to execute the above idea myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First join alll values by `join` and then use `apply` with comprehension for map values converted to lowercase:

```
s = (df2.assign(Word=df2['Word'].str.lower())
       .set_index('Word')[["count","Points","Percentage"]]
       .astype(str)
       .apply(' '.join, axis=1))


df1['text'] = df1['text'].str.lower().apply(lambda x: ' '.join(s.get(y) for y in x.split()))
print (df1)
   id                                               text
0   1  2 2 100.0 1 1 100.0 1 1 100.0 1 1 100.0 1 1 10...
1   2  2 2 100.0 3 1 33.33 1 1 100.0 1 1 100.0 1 1 10...
2   3                  2 -2 -100.0 1 -1 -100.0 3 1 33.33
3   4                            2 -2 -100.0 1 -1 -100.0
```

Comment: Hey. This do not remove the original string. This give me result like "1 1 100 world" After the 3 values, the original string also appear.

Comment: For example the result of last row is` 2 -2 -100.0 Good 1 -1 -100.0 Evening`

Comment: @JohnDoe - I change `.set_index('Word')` to `.set_index('Word')[["count","Points","Percentage"]]`, can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

I hope it helps you.

I just did it for first sentence.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=["text"],data=["Hello world how are you people"])
df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Word","count","Points","Percentage"],
                 data=[
                     ["hello",2,2,100],
                     ["world",1,1,100],
                      ["how",1,1,100],
                      ["are",1,1,100],
                      ["you",1,1,100],
                      ["people",3,1,33.33],
                 ])
```

The for every sentence in df1 for every word select "count","Points","Percentage" from df2 and add it to a string.

```
for i,row in df1.iterrows():
    new_string=""

    for word in row["text"].split(" "):
        values_from_df2=list(df2.loc[df2["Word"]==word.lower()][["count","Points","Percentage"]].values[0])
        new_string += ' '.join(str(int(e)) for e in values_from_df2)+" "

    row["text"] = new_string
```

Result:

```
    text
0   2 2 100 1 1 100 1 1 100 1 1 100 1 1 100 3 1 33
```